# Rails - how to set up path to action by own criteria (not ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, action, routes

When I have a path like this:

```
user_messages_path(current_user)
```

it generates following URL:

```
users/1/listings
```

I am storing in database users' unique codes, so I wouldn't like to display URLs like

```
users/ID/listings
```

but more like

```
users/CODE/listings
```

How I need to update routes for using paths with users' codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
user_messages_path(current_user)
```

is a shortcut for:

```
user_messages_path(current_user.to_param)
```

which generally does:

```
user_messages_path(current_user.id)
```

You can:

- pass any string you want: `user_messages_path('foo')`
- or override `to_param` in your model

Just beware to update your code responsible to retrieve the object from the params.

Answer (score 0):

in `user.rb`

```
def to_param
  uuid        # or whatever attribute you want to use instead of the id
end
```

in the controllers instead of `User.find(params[:id])`:

```
User.find_by_uuid!(params[:id]) # adjust to the attribute name used in to_param
```

Comment: There is one thing - in the `listings` table and other tables, there is the column called `user_id` - this can be a problem, or not? Don't I need to rework this part as well?

Comment: Depends: I expect you to have a finder in your listings controller like this: `User.find(params[:user_id]).listings.find(params[:id])`. This kind of finders must be changed like described above: `User.find_by_uuid!(params[:user_id]).listings.find(params[:id])`. If  you have something like `Listing.where(:user_id => params[:user_id]).all`, it cannot be rewritten und should be changed to `User.find_by_uuid!(params[:user_id]).listings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom route, something like the following.

```
get 'users/:code/:listings' => 'listings#index', as: :user_messages
```

Then in your params there key :code will return that part of the url e.g. params[:code]
In your controller you could use the following

Rails 3.2

```
 User.find_by_code(params[:code])
```

Rails 4

```
User.where(code: params[:code])
```